# Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, typeerror

I'm building a weather app in in Dart. When I parse the json from from the API i get this error: `_Exception (Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')` i'm not sure if it depends from the model or from the parsing method. igenerated the model with: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ but the parameter `RachaMax` didn't had a Class so i had to create it manually.
If i'm omitting any key information please let me know. thanks !

this is the service:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import 'models/first_call_model.dart';
import 'models/w_response_model.dart';

class WeatherService {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  static String _apiKey = *******;
  Future<FirstCallModel?> getFirstCall() async {
    dio
      ..interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(requestBody: true, responseBody: true));
    try {
      var response = await dio.get(
          'https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/prediccion/especifica/municipio/diaria/08022?api_key=$_apiKey');
      FirstCallModel? result = FirstCallModel.fromJson(response.data);
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }

  Future<WeatherResponseModel?> getHttp() async {
    dio
      ..interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(requestBody: true, responseBody: true));
    try {
      var response =
          await dio.get('https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/sh/1dfc874d');
      WeatherResponseModel? result =
          WeatherResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
}
```

these are the json objects:

```
[ {
  "origen" : {
    "productor" : "Agencia Estatal de Meteorología - AEMET. Gobierno de España",
    "web" : "https://www.aemet.es",
    "enlace" : "https://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/berga-id08022",
    "language" : "es",
    "copyright" : "© AEMET. Autorizado el uso de la información y su reproducción citando a AEMET como autora de la misma.",
    "notaLegal" : "https://www.aemet.es/es/nota_legal"
  },
  "elaborado" : "2022-10-22T11:37:21",
  "nombre" : "Berga",
  "provincia" : "Barcelona",
  "prediccion" : {
    "dia" : [ {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24",
        "descripcion" : ""
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12",
        "descripcion" : ""
      }, {
        "value" : "12",
        "periodo" : "12-24",
        "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-06",
        "descripcion" : ""
      }, {
        "value" : "12",
        "periodo" : "06-12",
        "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "12",
        "periodo" : "12-18",
        "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "12",
        "periodo" : "18-24",
        "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 15,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "C",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 15,
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "SE",
        "velocidad" : 5,
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "C",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 22,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 12,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 20,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 17,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 14,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 22,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 12,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 20,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 17,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 14,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 75,
        "minima" : 45,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 75,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 45,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 65,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 75,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "uvMax" : 3,
      "fecha" : "2022-10-22T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 95,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 85,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 95,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : 85,
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 85,
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : 40,
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "26",
        "periodo" : "00-24",
        "descripcion" : "Cubierto con lluvia"
      }, {
        "value" : "54",
        "periodo" : "00-12",
        "descripcion" : "Cubierto con tormenta"
      }, {
        "value" : "54",
        "periodo" : "12-24",
        "descripcion" : "Cubierto con tormenta"
      }, {
        "value" : "14n",
        "periodo" : "00-06",
        "descripcion" : "Nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "64",
        "periodo" : "06-12",
        "descripcion" : "Cubierto con tormenta y lluvia escasa"
      }, {
        "value" : "64",
        "periodo" : "12-18",
        "descripcion" : "Cubierto con tormenta y lluvia escasa"
      }, {
        "value" : "14",
        "periodo" : "18-24",
        "descripcion" : "Nuboso"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "C",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "C",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "C",
        "velocidad" : 0,
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-06"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "06-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-18"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "18-24"
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 21,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 15,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 20,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 17,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 14,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 21,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 15,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 20,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 17,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 14,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 90,
        "minima" : 50,
        "dato" : [ {
          "value" : 80,
          "hora" : 6
        }, {
          "value" : 60,
          "hora" : 12
        }, {
          "value" : 60,
          "hora" : 18
        }, {
          "value" : 75,
          "hora" : 24
        } ]
      },
      "uvMax" : 3,
      "fecha" : "2022-10-23T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "17",
        "periodo" : "00-24",
        "descripcion" : "Nubes altas"
      }, {
        "value" : "17",
        "periodo" : "00-12",
        "descripcion" : "Nubes altas"
      }, {
        "value" : "17",
        "periodo" : "12-24",
        "descripcion" : "Nubes altas"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "O",
        "velocidad" : 15,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "O",
        "velocidad" : 15,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "O",
        "velocidad" : 15,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 22,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 22,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 80,
        "minima" : 35,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "uvMax" : 3,
      "fecha" : "2022-10-24T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 10,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : 0,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : 5,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "14",
        "periodo" : "00-24",
        "descripcion" : "Nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "14",
        "periodo" : "00-12",
        "descripcion" : "Nuboso"
      }, {
        "value" : "14",
        "periodo" : "12-24",
        "descripcion" : "Nuboso"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 10,
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-24"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "00-12"
      }, {
        "value" : "",
        "periodo" : "12-24"
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 23,
        "minima" : 11,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 23,
        "minima" : 11,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 70,
        "minima" : 45,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "uvMax" : 3,
      "fecha" : "2022-10-25T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 5
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "17",
        "descripcion" : "Nubes altas"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "SO",
        "velocidad" : 10
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 26,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 26,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 70,
        "minima" : 30,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "uvMax" : 3,
      "fecha" : "2022-10-26T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 0
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "17",
        "descripcion" : "Nubes altas"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 5
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 25,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 25,
        "minima" : 13,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 55,
        "minima" : 25,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "fecha" : "2022-10-27T00:00:00"
    }, {
      "probPrecipitacion" : [ {
        "value" : 10
      } ],
      "cotaNieveProv" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "estadoCielo" : [ {
        "value" : "13",
        "descripcion" : "Intervalos nubosos"
      } ],
      "viento" : [ {
        "direccion" : "S",
        "velocidad" : 5
      } ],
      "rachaMax" : [ {
        "value" : ""
      } ],
      "temperatura" : {
        "maxima" : 23,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "sensTermica" : {
        "maxima" : 23,
        "minima" : 12,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "humedadRelativa" : {
        "maxima" : 50,
        "minima" : 30,
        "dato" : [ ]
      },
      "fecha" : "2022-10-28T00:00:00"
    } ]
  },
  "id" : 8022,
  "version" : 1.0
} ]
```

this is the model:

```
class WeatherResponseModel {
  Origen? origen;
  String? elaborado;
  String? nombre;
  String? provincia;
  Prediccion? prediccion;
  int? id;
  int? version;

  WeatherResponseModel(
      {this.origen,
      this.elaborado,
      this.nombre,
      this.provincia,
      this.prediccion,
      this.id,
      this.version});

  WeatherResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    origen =
        json['origen'] != null ? new Origen.fromJson(json['origen']) : null;
    elaborado = json['elaborado'];
    nombre = json['nombre'];
    provincia = json['provincia'];
    prediccion = json['prediccion'] != null
        ? new Prediccion.fromJson(json['prediccion'])
        : null;
    id = json['id'];
    version = json['version'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.origen != null) {
      data['origen'] = this.origen!.toJson();
    }
    data['elaborado'] = this.elaborado;
    data['nombre'] = this.nombre;
    data['provincia'] = this.provincia;
    if (this.prediccion != null) {
      data['prediccion'] = this.prediccion!.toJson();
    }
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['version'] = this.version;
    return data;
  }
}

class Origen {
  String? productor;
  String? web;
  String? enlace;
  String? language;
  String? copyright;
  String? notaLegal;

  Origen(
      {this.productor,
      this.web,
      this.enlace,
      this.language,
      this.copyright,
      this.notaLegal});

  Origen.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productor = json['productor'];
    web = json['web'];
    enlace = json['enlace'];
    language = json['language'];
    copyright = json['copyright'];
    notaLegal = json['notaLegal'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['productor'] = this.productor;
    data['web'] = this.web;
    data['enlace'] = this.enlace;
    data['language'] = this.language;
    data['copyright'] = this.copyright;
    data['notaLegal'] = this.notaLegal;
    return data;
  }
}

class Prediccion {
  List<Dia>? dia;

  Prediccion({this.dia});

  Prediccion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['dia'] != null) {
      dia = <Dia>[];
      json['dia'].forEach((v) {
        dia!.add(new Dia.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.dia != null) {
      data['dia'] = this.dia!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Dia {
  List<ProbPrecipitacion>? probPrecipitacion;
  List<CotaNieveProv>? cotaNieveProv;
  List<EstadoCielo>? estadoCielo;
  List<Viento>? viento;
  List<RachaMax>? rachaMax;
  Temperatura? temperatura;
  Temperatura? sensTermica;
  Temperatura? humedadRelativa;
  int? uvMax;
  String? fecha;

  Dia(
      {this.probPrecipitacion,
      this.cotaNieveProv,
      this.estadoCielo,
      this.viento,
      this.rachaMax,
      this.temperatura,
      this.sensTermica,
      this.humedadRelativa,
      this.uvMax,
      this.fecha});

  Dia.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['probPrecipitacion'] != null) {
      probPrecipitacion = <ProbPrecipitacion>[];
      json['probPrecipitacion'].forEach((v) {
        probPrecipitacion!.add(new ProbPrecipitacion.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['cotaNieveProv'] != null) {
      cotaNieveProv = <CotaNieveProv>[];
      json['cotaNieveProv'].forEach((v) {
        cotaNieveProv!.add(new CotaNieveProv.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['estadoCielo'] != null) {
      estadoCielo = <EstadoCielo>[];
      json['estadoCielo'].forEach((v) {
        estadoCielo!.add(new EstadoCielo.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['viento'] != null) {
      viento = <Viento>[];
      json['viento'].forEach((v) {
        viento!.add(new Viento.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['rachaMax'] != null) {
      rachaMax = <RachaMax>[];
      json['rachaMax'].forEach((v) {
        rachaMax!.add(new RachaMax.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    temperatura = json['temperatura'] != null
        ? new Temperatura.fromJson(json['temperatura'])
        : null;
    sensTermica = json['sensTermica'] != null
        ? new Temperatura.fromJson(json['sensTermica'])
        : null;
    humedadRelativa = json['humedadRelativa'] != null
        ? new Temperatura.fromJson(json['humedadRelativa'])
        : null;
    uvMax = json['uvMax'];
    fecha = json['fecha'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.probPrecipitacion != null) {
      data['probPrecipitacion'] =
          this.probPrecipitacion!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.cotaNieveProv != null) {
      data['cotaNieveProv'] =
          this.cotaNieveProv!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.estadoCielo != null) {
      data['estadoCielo'] = this.estadoCielo!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.viento != null) {
      data['viento'] = this.viento!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.rachaMax != null) {
      data['rachaMax'] = this.rachaMax!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.temperatura != null) {
      data['temperatura'] = this.temperatura!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.sensTermica != null) {
      data['sensTermica'] = this.sensTermica!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.humedadRelativa != null) {
      data['humedadRelativa'] = this.humedadRelativa!.toJson();
    }
    data['uvMax'] = this.uvMax;
    data['fecha'] = this.fecha;
    return data;
  }
}

class ProbPrecipitacion {
  int? value;
  String? periodo;

  ProbPrecipitacion({this.value, this.periodo});

  ProbPrecipitacion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'];
    periodo = json['periodo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['value'] = this.value;
    data['periodo'] = this.periodo;
    return data;
  }
}

class CotaNieveProv {
  String? value;
  String? periodo;

  CotaNieveProv({this.value, this.periodo});

  CotaNieveProv.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'];
    periodo = json['periodo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['value'] = this.value;
    data['periodo'] = this.periodo;
    return data;
  }
}

class EstadoCielo {
  String? value;
  String? periodo;
  String? descripcion;

  EstadoCielo({this.value, this.periodo, this.descripcion});

  EstadoCielo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'];
    periodo = json['periodo'];
    descripcion = json['descripcion'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['value'] = this.value;
    data['periodo'] = this.periodo;
    data['descripcion'] = this.descripcion;
    return data;
  }
}

class Viento {
  String? direccion;
  int? velocidad;
  String? periodo;

  Viento({this.direccion, this.velocidad, this.periodo});

  Viento.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    direccion = json['direccion'];
    velocidad = json['velocidad'];
    periodo = json['periodo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['direccion'] = this.direccion;
    data['velocidad'] = this.velocidad;
    data['periodo'] = this.periodo;
    return data;
  }
}

class RachaMax {
  String? direccion;
  int? velocidad;
  String? periodo;

  RachaMax({this.direccion, this.velocidad, this.periodo});

  RachaMax.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    direccion = json['direccion'];
    velocidad = json['velocidad'];
    periodo = json['periodo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['direccion'] = this.direccion;
    data['velocidad'] = this.velocidad;
    data['periodo'] = this.periodo;
    return data;
  }
}

class Temperatura {
  int? maxima;
  int? minima;
  List<Dato>? dato;

  Temperatura({this.maxima, this.minima, this.dato});

  Temperatura.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    maxima = json['maxima'];
    minima = json['minima'];
    if (json['dato'] != null) {
      dato = <Dato>[];
      json['dato'].forEach((v) {
        dato!.add(new Dato.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['maxima'] = this.maxima;
    data['minima'] = this.minima;
    if (this.dato != null) {
      data['dato'] = this.dato!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Dato {
  int? value;
  int? hora;

  Dato({this.value, this.hora});

  Dato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    value = json['value'];
    hora = json['hora'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['value'] = this.value;
    data['hora'] = this.hora;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `WeatherResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` You need to decode the  response data like

```dart
FirstCallModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.data))
```

Same goes for other model class. Also you can change on model class

Comment: I tried what you suggested before, but it actually generate an exception in `FirstCallModel? result = FirstCallModel.fromJson(response.data);` whereas before, this line didn't show any exception. It says: ' type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' '